# byte[] to string an string to byte[]

Tags: byte

i know this was handled a lot here, but i couldnt solve my problem yet:
I read bytes from a Parceble Object and save them in a byte[], then I unmurshall
them back to an Object an it works all fine. But i have to send the bytes as a String, so i 
have to convert the bytes to string and then return.

I thought it would work as follow:

```
byte[] bytes = p1.marshall(); //get my object as bytes
String str = bytes.toString();
byte[] someBytes = str.getBytes();
```

But it doesnt Work, when I  "p2.unmarshall(someBytes, 0, someBytes.length);" with someBytes, but when I p2.unmarshall(bytes, 0, bytes.length); with bytes, it works fine. How can i convert bytes to String right?

Comment: I assume this is in Java?

Comment: How can we comment on code that we cannot see?

Answer (score 3):

You've got three problems here:

- You're calling `toString()` on `byte[]`, which is just going to give you something like `"[B@15db9742"`
- You're assuming you can just convert a byte array into text with no specific conversion, and not lose data
- You're calling `getBytes()` without specifying the character encoding, which is almost always a mistake.

In this case, you should just use base64 - that's almost always the right thing to do when converting *arbitrary* binary data to text. (If you were actually trying to decode encoded text, you should use `new String(bytes, charset)`, but that's not the case here.)

So, using [`android.util.Base64`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html):

```
String str = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
byte[] someBytes = Base64.decode(str, Base64.DEFAULT);
```